# Bounds of an ImageView is zero in ViewDidLayoutSubviews()

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am following Raywenderlich tutorial on `UIScrollView` that can pan and zoom an image (https://www.raywenderlich.com/159481/uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started). My code is exactly the same as theirs except that I created the views and layout constraints programmatically. Mine doesn't work.

I found the problem being my `ImageView` has a zero `bounds` value in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. But there shouldn't be any difference whether I created the constraints in Storyboard or in code, right? If so, any suggestion for workaround would be appreciated. The part in `viewDidLoad()` is my own code.

```
class ComposeController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    var imageViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var imageViewLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var imageViewTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var imageViewTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.image = MyImage //from Assets
        scrollView.delegate = self       
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageViewTopConstraint = imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor)
        imageViewBottomConstraint = imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor)
        imageViewLeadingConstraint = imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor)
        imageViewTrailingConstraint = imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.rightAnchor)
        imageViewTopConstraint.isActive = true
        imageViewBottomConstraint.isActive = true
        imageViewLeadingConstraint.isActive = true
        imageViewTrailingConstraint.isActive = true

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        updateMinZoomScaleForSize(view.bounds.size)
    }

    fileprivate func updateMinZoomScaleForSize(_ size: CGSize) {
        let widthScale = size.width / imageView.bounds.width
        let heightScale = size.height / imageView.bounds.height
        let minScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
        scrollView.zoomScale = minScale
    }
}

extension ComposeController: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44555450/1305067

Comment: @paulvs. Works perfectly thank you. Performance wise, does it matter whether I call them in `viewDidLoad()` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`?

Comment: I think you should call them in `viewDidLoad` as it is called before `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Apple's documentation for `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`:

> When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this method. However, this method being called does not indicate that the individual layouts of the view's subviews have been adjusted. Each subview is responsible for adjusting its own layout.

You can get the view to layout the individual subviews by calling:

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as my answer referenced in the question's comments.

Comment: Yes, you are right @paulvs.  You should post your answer as a full answer, as it's much more thorough than mine.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you @creeperspeak. I am curious through why one doesn't need to do so if the constraints are set in Storyboard

Comment: @JGuo You probably still would, if trying to get correct sizes in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  I've never tried, tbh.